# Why is my `git diff` now showing old mode and new mode instead of the differences in values of my local branch vs. master branch?

Tags: git

When I used to run `git diff requirements.txt` for the longest time it would show me the difference between the value of `requirements.txt` in my local git vs. master branch.

But now when I run it, I get:

```
diff --git a/requirements.txt b/requirements.txt
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

I am so confused...

Did I accidentally mess with the config?

Comment: This is simply the Unix rights changed to executable. Run `chmod 644 requirements.txt` and commit new rights.